# Unapproved transaction on BaseL2 **basically my funds have been stock for a minute now**

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, pending-transactions, coinbase, optimism

I currently have an unapproved transaction on the Base L2, and it's strange that my wallet is essentially stuck on an unapproved transaction. I can't send any other transactions with that wallet. I tried canceling the transaction, but it had no effect, essentially leaving my funds locked in the transaction, which is frozen.
Do you have any idea how I can cancel the transaction? I tried sending another transaction with the same nonce to cancel the other one, but it's useless; it's just frozen on the unapproved status. Additionally, I can't change networks on my MetaMask. I transferred some funds from the mainnet to the Base L2 to conduct some tests, and I encountered this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

#ethereum #optimims #base #ethereumL2