Need to cancel a pending transaction to a smart contract. I AM NOT A DEV :(
Would really appreciate if you could help me out.
So i had almost no eth left and decided to be cheap by place a transaction with a very small gas fee. Now the transaction is pending more than 24h and I tried a couple of times to cancel it via metamask but it doesn't work.
I tried sending a transaction to myself with the same nonce but it also didn't work, cuz the nonce automatically increase by 1 and now i have 3 pending transactions. Maybe it also has to do that its a smart contract and requires additional input?
This is the transaction id: 0xf85e102b0d068f488c43b0584494dddb1d263ebb342da125ec6d0a910eb3beab
And this is my public adress: 0x501a3d612433B53B2b070B5ab7C59AF376C21154
Would really appreciate if somebody could help me out.
Cheers

Did they all go through about 20 minutes ago? If still any issues please see the answer here:  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/161991/unapproved-transaction-on-basel2-basically-my-funds-have-been-stock-for-a-minu/162276#162276
| Don't use the same wallet instance, use a different browser profile or browser.
